# NoSuchAlgorithmException: DH KeyPairGenerator not available on camel-ftp

Tags: ftp, apache-camel, sftp, jsch

I'm using Apache Camel in a project and when I needed to use the camel-ftp component to send some files to an remote server, I've got this exception:

```
com.jcraft.jsch.JSchException: Session.connect: java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException: DH KeyPairGenerator not available
```

I was wondering why it could be happening in my project. So, I've started a quick small project with camel-core and camel-ftp components only and I pasted the route there and it worked fine.

```
 from("file:data/input?noop=true")
    .log("Uploading file ${file:name}")
    .to("sftp://www.mydestination.com:22/../opt/tmp?autoCreate=false&username=MyUser&password=MyPassword&passiveMode=true")
    .log("Uploaded file ${file:name} complete.");
```

I'm using Apache Karaf to run OSGI Bundles (my application is one of them). I've checked in different environments but the result still beeing the exception.

I really don't know what it could be. Anyone has some ideas about what can be the possible cause of it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

DH KeyPair Generator is normally part of the JRE/JSE and should be included if your JDK (>BTW which exact JDK version are you using ?).
Given that, your error is probably due to a wrong classpath.

I suggest you to check the value of "-Djava.ext.dirs" property (and the contents of the corresponding folders), for instance:

Windows:
java -Djava.ext.dirs="C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_07\jre\lib\ext;C:\dir2"

Unix:
java -Djava.ext.dirs=$JAVA_HOME/jre/lib/ext:/dir2

You also need to specify/modify the Karaf security provider, take a look at:
https://karaf.apache.org/manual/latest/security

Comment: Hello, TacheDeChoco.

We're using the last version of JDK 8.

I'll try to do this and give a proper feedback ASAP.

Thank you for your help!